# How to select processor(MIPS R2000) in g++?

Tags: c++, g++

What is the command for selecting processor(MIPS R2000) in g++? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need a cross-compilation environment for your target platform. You might find an existing one or you may need to build your own cross-compiler using the gcc toolchain. There's no single way to do this - it will depend on the specifics of the target architecture. Specifically, is there already an operating system (e.g. Linux, BSD, etc.) running on your target system? What kind of userland does it use - your build chain will need the relevant C and C++ library as well as any other libraries you need to build and run your software. Or are you coding straight against the metal? In this case, you'll want to find existing bootstrap code for getting the system into a sensible state for running your code - rolling your own will not be easy.

Generally, you're probably best off finding an existing developer community centred around the platform in question and asking for advice there. They may have step-by-step instructions for getting started.

Note that the CPU alone is only part of the picture - for example, the ARM architecture is very popular, but compiling code for Android devices (Linux kernel with Android userland), iOS devices (xnu kernel with BSD- and OSX-derived iOS userland), a Nintendo DS or a Playstation Vita (probably no multitasking OS at all) will be *extremely* different, even though they all use ARM chips, in many cases even the same instruction set generation.